# Rotating the display programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, rotation, display, dev-mode

I'm looking for a way to rotate the display of one of my monitors programmatically.
I have two monitors set up on a desk mount, and I often use them in varying orientations when programming or using various other programs, and in order to change the orientation I jump into display settings and rotate it that way (so i can have one or both in portrait).

Call me lazy as i know thats hardly any hassle to do, but it would be nice to just have a quick little executable on my taskbar that i can run to instantly rotate one of the screens back and forth when i need to.

I've looked into it and found various explanations using DEVMODE structs etc, and it all seems like a really long winded process, is there really not an easier way to do this? Not a windows dll that has this functionailty already?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To save writing it yourself, you could use [the free (for personal use) utility `iRotate`](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm) which works OK on Windows 10.

Comment: I'd look into automating this by recording - something like [AutoIt Recorder](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it's not that hard to achieve this using the mentioned DEVMODE struct and native calls.
I've written a little wrapper that does this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Display
    {
        public enum Orientations
        {
            DEGREES_CW_0 = 0,
            DEGREES_CW_90 = 3,
            DEGREES_CW_180 = 2,
            DEGREES_CW_270 = 1
        }

        public static bool Rotate(uint DisplayNumber, Orientations Orientation)
        {
            if(DisplayNumber == 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DisplayNumber", DisplayNumber, "First display is 1.");

            bool result = false;

            DISPLAY_DEVICE d = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
            d.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(d);

            DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();

           if(!NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, DisplayNumber-1, ref d, 0))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DisplayNumber", DisplayNumber, "Number is greater than connected displays.");

            if (0 != NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(
                d.DeviceName, NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
            {
                if ((dm.dmDisplayOrientation + (int)Orientation) % 2 == 1) // Need to swap height and width?
                {
                    int temp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
                    dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
                    dm.dmPelsWidth = temp;
                }

                switch (Orientation)
                {
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_90:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_270;
                        break;
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_180:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_180;
                        break;
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_270:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_90;
                        break;
                    case Orientations.DEGREES_CW_0:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                DISP_CHANGE ret = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
                    d.DeviceName, ref dm, IntPtr.Zero,
                    DisplaySettingsFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, IntPtr.Zero);

                result = ret == 0;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static void ResetAllRotations()
        {
            try
            {
                uint i = 0;
                while (++i <= 64)
                {
                    Rotate(i, Orientations.DEGREES_CW_0);
                }
            }
            catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                // Everything is fine, just reached the last display
            }
        }
    }

    internal class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(
            string lpszDeviceName, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode, IntPtr hwnd,
            DisplaySettingsFlags dwflags, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(
            string lpDevice, uint iDevNum, ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice,
            uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        internal static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(
            string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode);

        public const int DMDO_DEFAULT = 0;
        public const int DMDO_90 = 1;
        public const int DMDO_180 = 2;
        public const int DMDO_270 = 3;

        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;

    }

    // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal struct DEVMODE
    {
        public const int CCHDEVICENAME = 32;
        public const int CCHFORMNAME = 32;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHDEVICENAME)]
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        public string dmDeviceName;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(32)]
        public Int16 dmSpecVersion;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(34)]
        public Int16 dmDriverVersion;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(36)]
        public Int16 dmSize;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(38)]
        public Int16 dmDriverExtra;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(40)]
        public DM dmFields;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
        Int16 dmOrientation;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(46)]
        Int16 dmPaperSize;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(48)]
        Int16 dmPaperLength;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(50)]
        Int16 dmPaperWidth;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
        Int16 dmScale;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(54)]
        Int16 dmCopies;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
        Int16 dmDefaultSource;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(58)]
        Int16 dmPrintQuality;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(44)]
        public POINTL dmPosition;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(52)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayOrientation;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(56)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayFixedOutput;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(60)]
        public short dmColor;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(62)]
        public short dmDuplex;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(64)]
        public short dmYResolution;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(66)]
        public short dmTTOption;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(68)]
        public short dmCollate;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(72)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCHFORMNAME)]
        public string dmFormName;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(102)]
        public Int16 dmLogPixels;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(104)]
        public Int32 dmBitsPerPel;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(108)]
        public Int32 dmPelsWidth;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(112)]
        public Int32 dmPelsHeight;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayFlags;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(116)]
        public Int32 dmNup;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(120)]
        public Int32 dmDisplayFrequency;
    }

    // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569(v=vs.85).aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    internal struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceString;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string DeviceKey;
    }

    // See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd162807(v=vs.85).aspx
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct POINTL
    {
        long x;
        long y;
    }

    internal enum DISP_CHANGE : int
    {
        Successful = 0,
        Restart = 1,
        Failed = -1,
        BadMode = -2,
        NotUpdated = -3,
        BadFlags = -4,
        BadParam = -5,
        BadDualView = -6
    }

    // http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/DisplayDeviceStateFlags.html
    [Flags()]
    internal enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags : int
    {
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
        MultiDriver = 0x2,
        /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
        PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
        /// <summary>Represents a pseudo device used to mirror application drawing for remoting or other purposes.</summary>
        MirroringDriver = 0x8,
        /// <summary>The device is VGA compatible.</summary>
        VGACompatible = 0x10,
        /// <summary>The device is removable; it cannot be the primary display.</summary>
        Removable = 0x20,
        /// <summary>The device has more display modes than its output devices support.</summary>
        ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
        Remote      = 0x4000000,
        Disconnect  = 0x2000000
    }

    // http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags.html
    [Flags()]
    internal enum DisplaySettingsFlags : int
    {
        CDS_NONE = 0,
        CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY      = 0x00000001,
        CDS_TEST                = 0x00000002,
        CDS_FULLSCREEN          = 0x00000004,
        CDS_GLOBAL              = 0x00000008,
        CDS_SET_PRIMARY         = 0x00000010,
        CDS_VIDEOPARAMETERS     = 0x00000020,
        CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000100,
        CDS_DISABLE_UNSAFE_MODES= 0x00000200,
        CDS_RESET               = 0x40000000,
        CDS_RESET_EX            = 0x20000000,
        CDS_NORESET             = 0x10000000
    }

    [Flags()]
    internal enum DM : int
    {
        Orientation         = 0x00000001,
        PaperSize           = 0x00000002,
        PaperLength         = 0x00000004,
        PaperWidth          = 0x00000008,
        Scale               = 0x00000010,
        Position            = 0x00000020,
        NUP                 = 0x00000040,
        DisplayOrientation  = 0x00000080,
        Copies              = 0x00000100,
        DefaultSource       = 0x00000200,
        PrintQuality        = 0x00000400,
        Color               = 0x00000800,
        Duplex              = 0x00001000,
        YResolution         = 0x00002000,
        TTOption            = 0x00004000,
        Collate             = 0x00008000,
        FormName            = 0x00010000,
        LogPixels           = 0x00020000,
        BitsPerPixel        = 0x00040000,
        PelsWidth           = 0x00080000,
        PelsHeight          = 0x00100000,
        DisplayFlags        = 0x00200000,
        DisplayFrequency    = 0x00400000,
        ICMMethod           = 0x00800000,
        ICMIntent           = 0x01000000,
        MediaType           = 0x02000000,
        DitherType          = 0x04000000,
        PanningWidth        = 0x08000000,
        PanningHeight       = 0x10000000,
        DisplayFixedOutput  = 0x20000000
    }
```

You can simply invoke the static Rotate-Function with the display number you want to rotate (Monitor 1=1, Monitor 2=2, etc.) and the degree you need.
Like this:

```
Display.Rotate(1, Display.Orientations.DEGREES_CW_180);
```

There is also a little short-hand function `ResetAllRotations()` to reset all displays.

Regards

Comment: Awesome, that makes it much clearer to me seeing how someone has used the DEVMODE structure to achieve what i needed, thank you!

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. It's already in the code: You query the DEVMODE struct with EnumDisplaySettings and afterwards you can check the dmDisplayOrientation-Flag.

Comment: @Yosh Thanks, in WPF it works perfectly, but in UWP it does't work. Please do you know if it's in UWP possible?

Comment: @Puty I haven't worked with UWP so far, but afaik it's not allowed to call user32 API functions in UWP. So my guess is that it's not possible this way.

Comment: @Puty, you could create a Windows Desktop Bridge project to have your UWP app execute the above code from a regular console or WPF app.