# Changing desktop screen orientation

Tags: python, linux, windows, fullscreen

Is there a way to change the screen orientation using python? On Ubuntu I can evoke `xrandr` through the `os` library, but what about Windows? I want to rotate the screen as a whole (as if the user pressed "ctrl+alt+down/right/left") and not just the app window. Although I'm asking for python, I can accept answers on other languages too (C++, JS, C#) as long as there is a way to do it on both, Linux and Windows (even if it is through a terminal call).

Answer (score 1):

Rotating the screen using C# - [Rotating the display programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288135/rotating-the-display-programmatically)

If you wanted to use Python, you could use the ctypes library to execute C functions - https://www.journaldev.com/31907/calling-c-functions-from-python.  Just follow the logic from the C# example and re-create it in Python.

The key here is that there are c functions that you need to invoke to actually rotate the screen, primarily ChangeDisplaySettingsExa - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsexa

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to use ChangeDisplaySettingsExA ? I didn't understand how I could use it to rotate the screen like the C# example.

Comment: FYSA link-only answers are frowned upon on S/O, next time give some code examples to supplement your links :)